How do I create an inline Higher Order Component in SvelteKit 2.5?
I'm asking in general, but I'll give you an example use-case. On a particular page I'm building, I'm using the Helper component from Flowbite-Svelte. I keep finding myself using <Helper color="red">...</Helper> to make the color red. It'd be nice to build a higher order component and just use that, e.g. <ErrorHelper>...</ErrorHelper>, where ErrorHelper automatically passes the color prop as red to Helper.
I've been looking on the web for an hour and can't find out how to make a higher order component. I tried myself and came up with this:
import { Helper } from 'flowbite-svelte';

class ErrorHelper extends Helper {
  constructor(vals) {
  const newVals = {...vals, props: {...vals.props, color: 'red'}}
    super(newVals);
  }
}

This works when I render the component using Storybook for Svelte, which I think uses Svelte WITHOUT using SvelteKit. But when I use the same code in my SvelteKit website, like this:
// src/routes/onboard/3/+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import OnboardStep3 from '$lib/components/OnboardStep3.svelte';
</script>

<OnboardStep3 />


I get this error:
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
    at /src/lib/components/OnboardStep3.svelte:17:28
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:156:16)
    at eval (/src/routes/onboard/3/+page.svelte:15:100)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:156:16)
    at Object.default (/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:48:43)
    at /node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/layout.svelte:5:41
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:156:16)
    at Object.default (/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:47:42)
    at eval (/src/routes/+layout.svelte:25:163)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:156:16)


Unless you disable SSR in SvelteKit, you will have to also create a valid SSR-component.
Unfortunately Svelte uses some internals rather than the public SSR API. I.e. you cannot just provide an object with a render function but need to provide and use $$render instead. (Both the client-side and the server-side APIs are significantly different in Svelte 5, so migration will be necessary either way.)
Here is an example:
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
import { Helper } from 'flowbite-svelte';

export const ErrorHelper = extend(Helper, { color: 'red' });

function extend(component, defaults) {
    const extendProps = props => ({ ...defaults, ...props });

    return browser
        ? class extends component {
            constructor(options) {
                const { props, ...rest } = options;
                super({
                    ...rest,
                    props: extendProps(props),
                });
            }
        }
        : {
            $$render(result, props, bindings, slots, context) {
                return component.$$render(
                    result,
                    extendProps(props),
                    bindings,
                    slots,
                    context
                );
            }
        }
}


This works. Thanks! But TypeScript doesn't like it. https://imgur.com/a/eUHfALy

Just assert it having the same type as the source component, I guess.

To others, be advised: this technique works for static values like { color: 'red' }, but doesn't seem to work for dynamic props. I was using const MyComponentWithForm = extend(MyComponent, { form }), and that, as expected, only got the initial form value. But even doing $: MyComponentWithForm = extend(MyComponent, { form }) did not change anything.
